Composition of a bijection with another random function
I've been going through Algebra by Maclane and Birkhoff, and a I've been stuck with the following problem:
If $f$ is a bijection, and $f\circ g$ is defined, then show that $g$ is an injection if and only if $f\circ g$ is one, and a surjection if and only if $f\circ g$ is one.
The main issue I struggle with is answering this formally. I understand the concept though.
Thank you in advance for your help

First of all, what formal definitions of bijection, injection, and surjection are being used in the text? Your proof has to use these. Now write them down and then try to show that they're satisfied.

Quote: A function f:S->T is injective when s1 =! s2 in S implies f(s1)=!f(s2) in T,... A function h:S->T is surjective when its image is the whole codomain T

If $f\circ g$ is an injection: let $s_1\ne s_2$ in the domain of $g$, then $f(g(s_1))\ne f(g(s_2))$ (because $f\circ g$ is a injection), then $g(s_1) \ne g(s_2)$ (because $f$ is a function), then $g$ is an injection. Similarly for the other direction and the other -jection.

This is a common fact. Let's use the definitions you gave:

A function $f : S \to T$ is injective when $s_1 \ne s_2 \in S \implies f (s_1) \ne f (s_2) \in T$. A function $h : S \to T$ is surjective when its image is $T$.

Note that the definition for injectivity is equivalent to $f (s_1) = f (s_2) \implies s_1 = s_2$.
Let $g : S \to T$ and $f : T \to U$. Suppose that $f$ is bijective, hence both injective and surjective.
($g$ is injective $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f \circ g$ is injective) For the forward direction, consider arbitrary $s_1, s_2 \in S$ such that $f (g (s_1)) = f (g (s_2)) \in U$. Since $f$ is injective, it follows that $g (s_1) = g (s_2) \in T$. Since $g$ is injective, it follows that $s_1 = s_2$. This shows $f \circ g$ is injective. Conversely, let $s_1, s_2 \in S$ such that $g (s_1) = g (s_2) \in T$. Apply $f$ to see that $f (g (s_1)) = f (g (s_2)) \in U$. But since $f \circ g$ is injective, then we have $s_1 = s_2$. This shows $g$ is injective. Note that for this equivalence, it was only necessary that $f$ be injective.
($g$ is surjective $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f \circ g$ is surjective) For the forward direction, let $u \in U$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is surjective, there is some $t \in T$ such that $f (t) = u$. And since $g$ is surjective, there is some $s \in S$ such that $g (s) = t$. Clearly, $s$ is a preimage of $u$ under $f \circ g$, since $(f \circ g) (s) = f (g (s)) = f (t) = u$. This shows $f \circ g$ is surjective. For the converse, let $t \in T$ be arbitrary. The function $f$ maps $t$ to some element, say $u = f (t) \in U$. Since $f \circ g$ is surjective, there is some element $s \in S$ such that $(f \circ g) (s) = u$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $g (s) \ne t$. Since $f$ is injective, this implies that $f (g (s)) = (f \circ g) (s) \ne f (t) = u$, an obvious contradiction. So, it must be that $g (s) = t$. This shows $g$ is surjective. Note that for this equivalence, it was necessary that $f$ be bijective.
